# Inserting a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert

I need some help with my code... I need to insert into two tables

```
DECLARE @IDENTITY INT

INSERT INTO BestallningMatratt (MatrattID, BestallningID, Antal)
VALUES ('1', '2', '3')

SELECT @IDENTITY = @@IDENTITY FROM BestallningMatratt

INSERT INTO Bestallning (BestallningID, BestallningDatum, Totalbelopp, Levererad, KundID)
VALUES (@IDENTITY, '28-02-2014', '250', '1', '1')
```

I get error when I run my code

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_BestallningMatratt_Bestallning". The conflict occurred in database "Tomasos", table "dbo.Bestallning", column 'BestallningID'.
>
> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Bestallning' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: So what exactly do  you need help with?

Comment: Without knowing the table schema it's difficult to tell, but it looks like you are trying to insert out of order.  You need to add a record to `Bestallning` first, then insert `@@IDENTITY` in `BestallningMatratt.BestallningID`.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 2):

FIrst, you need to make sure you are inserting to the tables in the correct order. The parent table is always the first to be inserted into. Your error message makes me feel that this is possibly the case here. I would have to see the actual table structures to be postive.

Next in writing code, you should know the structure of your tables and know what fields are identity fields and NEVER attempt to insert into those fields directly (Unless you are a dba who has many years of experieince). Especially not from an application or stored proc. Identity_insert is for the special case of transferring data from one system to another and should NOT be used for anything else. Do not follow any directions to use identity_insert at your current level of knowledge.

And finally there is no circumstance where you should be using @@identity to grab the identity value to insert to another table. You can get incorrect results from this and it is a SQL antipattern to use it. If someone adds a trigger to the table that inserts to another table with an identity is is this one that will be returend. SInce you can't predict when someone might do this, it is likely you will only findout you have a problem when the data integrity is so thoroughly messed up that is is almost impossible to fix. Never do anythign that puts data integrity at risk.  The best method is to use the OUTPUT clause, the second best method is to use Scope_Identity(). @@Identity is very risky and if you have used it anywhere, it should be replaced immediately.

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding the below... while the code below **may** solve your problem, it doesn't change the fact that the practice of manually creating identities could cause major problems with your data, and should only be performed in rare circumstances by those who are experienced enough to know what they're doing and why this is the only solution.*

---

I would strongly recommend against inserting the identity value wherever you can avoid it, plus it appears as though your operations are out of order.  It looks like BastallningMatratt is a child table dependent upon the FK from Bestallning.
Assuming that is the case (and that you *still* need to insert an identity key manually into BestallningMatratt so that its key is "1", try the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tomasos ON;
GO

DECLARE @IDENTITY INT

INSERT INTO Bestallning (BestallningDatum, Totalbelopp, Levererad, KundID)
VALUES ('28-02-2014', '250', '1', '1')

SELECT @IDENTITY = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO BestallningMatratt (MatrattID, BestallningID, Antal)
VALUES ('1', @IDENTITY, '3')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tomasos OFF;
GO
```

Comment: I downvoted this because while it may fix the error message is is highly unlikely to fix the actual problem.  And if it does not it will end up causing a much worse data problem. When someone clearly doesn't understand what he or she is doing, it is very dangerous to suggest a practice that someone inexperienced should not be using.

Comment: I can't argue with that. :)